# Display scrollbars for overflown content only on parent container

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to achieve is to have only scrollbars on the div with `overflow: auto`. Why do I see additional vertical scrollbar on the body?

```html
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 100vh; width: 100%;">
    <div style="width: 4000px;height: 4000px;background: green;">       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

By adding `overflow: hidden` to the parent you deactivate the scrollbars, also you additionally may add:

```
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

This would work out like this:

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 100vh; width: 100%;">
    <div style="width: 4000px;height: 4000px;background: green;">       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the margin and padding from the document container like this:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 100vh; width: 100%;">
    <div style="width: 4000px;height: 4000px;background: green;">       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess I should get some sleep... Thanks!